# Open IOS keyboard on Focus of element

Tags: jquery, ios, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using directive to trigger focus to input field when user click on on link. It's working fine everywhere as expected except IOS. It's not opening the keyboard on ios devices(iphone/ipad) on focus.It adds the blue border around input which shows that it's focusing. How can i open the keyboard in ios device on focus ?

HTML

```
 <a data-mya-triggerfocus="something" >Something</a>
 <input name="something" id="something" />
```

JS

```
   angular.module('app').directive('myaTriggerfocus', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    var otherElement = document.querySelector('#' + attrs.myaTriggerfocus);  
                        otherElement.focus();      
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does putting a "type" attribute help?

```
<a data-mya-triggerfocus="something" >Something</a>
<input name="something" **type="text"** id="something" />
```

To display a numeric keyboard then you may try:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

I am trying to recollect about Apple's documentation suggesting to - set the value of the pattern attribute to "[0-9]*" or "d*" in order to open the numeric keypad. Not sure if it is relevant here. Just saying..

Comment: Nops. It's not helping out. Focus is turning the border to blue but not actually putting the cursor in and opening the keyboard. Any suggestion how to trigger the "TOUCH" event ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>
```

in your config.xml file for your app.

(That's according to the definition of the ios)